# Is there a name for kanji with the same ON and KUN readings?

Tags: kanji, readings

Is there a name for kanji with the same *on* and *kun* reading? I mean kanji like 労.

Comment: ロウ is not a _kun_ reading.

Comment: ろう.する is in kun readings on jisho.org. Am I missing the point? Or is it wrong to say that ろう is a kun reading in this case? Should I say that ろうする is the kun reading instead?

Comment: Dictionary says the kun reading of 労 is つかれる,　いたわる,　ねぎらう but　there is a verb of 労(ろう)する. This ろう is on reading and there are some verbs which one on reading kanji + する like 乗(じょう)ずる.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure there are kanji that have the same *on* and *kun* reading and if there are, they would be extremely rare. For this to happen you would have to have a native Japanese word (at most two morae), which happens to be pronounced like a *on* reading (quite unlikely) and that word happens to be the *on* reading of the *kanji* that matches the meaning of the original Japanese word (extremely unlikely).

For example, か "mosquito" could be an *on* reading of a kanji. But it's not the *on* reading of the kanji that matches the meaning "mosquito", which would be 蚊【ブン】. So, we get 蚊 with *kun* reading か and *on* reading ブン.

---

It may happen that the *on* reading of a single kanji may be used as a word by itself (e.g. 駅). That doesn't make the reading a *kun* reading.

Also, sometimes the *on* reading of a kanji may be used in verbs (e.g. 愛す or 転じる). Even if the verb can be written in hiragana (as in あいす or てんじる), that doesn't make the reading (あい or てん) a *kun* reading. These verbs, that look like

> [*on* reading] + す
>   [*on* reading] + じる
>   [*on* reading] + ずる

are fossilized versions of

> [*on* reading] + する

as in 勉強する "to study" and you will agree that べんきょう isn't a *kun* reading of 勉強 just because it appears in べんきょうする.

Comment: Are you saying that in 労する kanji 労 is read by ON? And one should not say that in this case ON and one of the KUN readings are the same?

Comment: Yes, the reading of 労 in 労する is the _on_ reading and you can't say that _on_ and _kun_ readings are the same. (労 doesn't have a _kun_ reading ろう.)

Comment: Thank you for your clarifications. I guess I was misled by the way they give ON and KUN readings on jisho.org and imiwa.

Comment: こんなのありました・・・全部あってるかどうかわかりませんけど。
　http://www13.atpages.jp/shimapucchi/newpage17.html

Comment: @choco Thank you. This is what I was looking for! =)

Answer (score 6):

A few kanji do have the same on- and kun-readings. In the [joyo-kanji list](http://kokugo.bunka.go.jp/kokugo_nihongo/joho/kijun/naikaku/kanji/joyokanjisakuin/),

- [死](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/92455/meaning/m0u/)

  - on: シ as in 死亡【シボウ】 (death), 死体【シタイ】 (corpse)
  - kun: 死【し】ぬ (to die)
- [架](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/srch/jn/%E6%9E%B6/m0u/)

  - on: カ as in 高架【コウカ】 (elevated/raised (road)), 担架【タンカ】 (stretcher)
  - kun: 架【か】ける (to build (a bridge))

I don't know the name for this type of kanji. These are probably mere coincidences and I wonder if this will help people learn Japanese.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I hoped there were more. Now I understand there are very few such kanji. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Strictly speaking, 死ぬ's base is _sin-_ and 架ける（架かる） _kak-_.