# Similar 音・訓読み: Coincidence, or something more?

Tags: etymology

Occasionally, some 漢字 will have quite similar 音読み and 訓読み; such as, for instance 困; with 困{コン} and 困{こま}る; or 灰 with 灰{はい} and 灰{カイ}.

Are these cases exclusively coincidence, or are there situations in which Chinese words have been fully internalised as Japanese words rather than Sino-Japanese loanwords? (Or even; Japanese words exported to Chinese as fully internalised loanwords?)

**Edit:**

Thanks to naruto's comment; I remembered the one I *really* wanted to ask about (it was nagging at me as I wrote the question): 死, with 死{し}ぬ and 死{シ}.

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32285/5010

Comment: @naruto That was the one. It was nagging at me as I wrote the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the etymologies independently:

#### 灰

This term appears in the [*Man'yōshū*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man'y%C5%8Dsh%C5%AB) poetry compilation completed circa 759, so this is an older word.  The older kana spelling of this was はひ, indicating an Old Japanese reading of `/papi/`.

Meanwhile, the on'yomi has an older kana spelling of くわい (probably realized as `/kwai/`), closer to the Middle Chinese it came from, which has a reconstructed reading of `/xwoj/` -- think of the `/x/` as a hard **H** like in Scottish *loch*, and think of the `/j/` on the end like a **Y**.

The older kun'yomi of `/papi/` doesn't overlap with the older on'yomi of `/kwai/` in any way that I can find, so I think the similarity between modern on'yomi *kai* and kun'yomi *hai* is purely a coincidence of historical phonetic development.

#### 困

The *komaru* reading with a sense of "stuck, troubled" only seems to appear from the early [Edo period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edo_period), from what I can find.  I suspect this is an extension from / alteration of ancient root verb 込{こ}む "to go into something; to put something into something else", much like the English "stuck" can be interpreted as the passive participle form of root verb "stick" (as in, "to *be* stuck [into a bad situation]").

The older root's sense of "into" doesn't overlap much with the 困 kanji's meaning of "besieged, troubled", so I suspect this similarity is another coincidence of historical semantic development.

#### Other cases

Although the above two are coincidental, there *are* cases where the kun'yomi developed from the on'yomi.  One example is 文{ふみ}, where the kun'yomi of *fumi* apparently came from an older on'yomi of *pun*.  More at [the Wiktionary entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%96%87#Japanese).

In general, sound similarities are *probably* accidental.  To find out for sure, you have to dig into the historical development of each term.

Comment: 文 being a fully internalised loan word makes a lot of sense; seeing as how it's a fully internalised loan concept as well.