# Identical on and kun readings

Tags: kanji, readings

死 is read either し or シ. What would be the difference compared to there being only one reading?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/32292/5010 But what do you mean by "difference"? This is probably just a coincidence, and I don't think there is a deep meaning...

Comment: 死 has two readings, indeed -- but し and シ are two renderings of the same reading, //ɕi//.  The other reading is less common, and it's //ɕini//.  The //ni// is often written with the _okurigana_, but it's sometimes left implied, as in 死神 (_shinigami_).

Answer (score -1):

I am a Japanese.

in the case of "onyomi", we often use "katakana" like "シ".

"死神" can be read as the whole of the word, like "shinigami"